# can not start with hardware control AVD android studio 1.0.2

Tags: android

1] I want this type of avd.

[image]

2] But it display like this

[image]

3] alert like this image - for this solution i select like image 4

[image]

4] i want avd like image 1 but now it display like image 2

[image]
im using android studio 1.0.2
what is the solution for this.